# Does Ghost Touch work on every damage type of the weapon?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, incorporeal

If you hit a [Wraith](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=417) with a Rapier that has a Ghost Touch and a Frost rune, how much cold damage does it take?

The Wraith has resist 5 all, except for Ghost Touch:

> **Resistances** all 5 (except force, ghost touch, or positive; double resistance vs. non-magical)

[Ghost Touch](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=297) is not very clear:

> A ghost touch weapon is particularly effective against incorporeal creatures, which almost always have a specific vulnerability to ghost touch weapons.

So the question is if [Frost](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=296) is part of the weapon:

> This weapon is empowered with freezing ice. *It* deals an additional 1d6 cold damage on a successful Strike.

The "*it*" there seems to mean that the cold damage is not separate, so the Ghost Touch lets all of it through.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes

> A resistance also might have an exception. For example, resistance 10 to physical damage (except silver) would reduce any physical damage by 10 unless that damage was dealt by a silver weapon.

All damage dealt by a *ghost touch* weapon would trigger a weakness or [resistance exception](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=346) like what the wraith has.